# Why chain of flatMap stops on first Left value but continues on Right values

Tags: scala, flatmap, either

I don't understand this line: 
`Right(1).flatMap(_ => Left(2)).flatMap(_ => Left(3))`

`Right(1)` is passed to `.flatMap(_ => Left(2)`. It returns `Left(2)` which is passed to `.flatMap(_ => Left(3)`. And it should've returned `Left(3)`. But it returns `Left(2)`.

Why is that so?

Another example is `Right(1).flatMap(_ => Right(2)).flatMap(_ => Right(3))`

It returns `Right(3)` (as it should have).

From what I understand it works as follows:
`Right(1)` is passed to `.flatMap(_ => Right(2))`. It returns `Right(2)` which is passed to `.flatMap(_ => Right(3)`. At the end it returns `Right(3)`

[Scala fiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/IeGUm6C)

Comment: **Either** is right-biased. It means that operations like `map` & `flatMap` only work on the **Right** and shortcircuit when you have a **Left**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that starting from Scala 2.12 Either is *right-biased*. It means that operations like flatMap will stop computing, when the result is left. Check the implementation to understand it:

```
def flatMap[EE >: E, B](f: A => Either[EE, B]): Either[EE, B] =
  this match {
    case Left(value)  => Left(value)
    case Right(value) => f(value)
  }
```

So as you can see in the case of Left it construct's Left with the value extracted from it *without applying f*.

Answer (score 1):

`flatmap` is `Right` associated. What I mean by that is that it will only operate on `Right` values, and not on `Left` values. This allows the sequence of `flatMaps` to shortcuirt when it hits the first `Left`.

See the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html#flatMap[AA%3E:A,Y](f:B=%3Escala.util.Either[AA,Y]):scala.util.Either[AA,Y]) for more examples of this:

Answer (score 1):

The chain of flat-mapped computations is short-circuited on the first evaluated `Left` due to `Either` monad being *success-biased* on the `Right` values. The reason for such bias is that programers often interpreted left side to represent an error result of computation, whilst the right hand side would mean the successful result of computation. So if left means error, there is not much point in continuing computing with error down the chain, hence the chain is broken.

Note, the `Either` monad used to be biased only by convention. Conventional right-bias of `Either` was [formalised in Scala 2.12](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#either-is-now-right-biased). Some argue `Either` should be unbiased, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25469378/5205022),

> If you use Either for error reporting, then it is true that you want
> it to be biased to one side, but that is only one use-case of many, and
> hardcoding a single; special use-case into a general interface smells of
> bad design. And for that use-case, you might just as well use Try,
> which is basically a biased Either.

whilst others argue favouring one side, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48763247/5205022),

> ... with Scala 2.12. it became right-biased, which is IMHO a better
> design choice, and fits perfectly with other similar sum types from
> other libraries. For example, it’s very easy now to go from Either to
> / (scalaz dicjuntion) now that there is no bias mismatch. They are
> completely isomorphic.

Nevertheless, bias of `Either` does not force semantics of just “happy/unhappy”, for example, the requirement in [Creating a method which returns one or two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946591/creating-a-method-which-returns-one-or-two-parameters-generically/57947251#57947251) may be addressed with `Either` where left side is interpreted as a happy/successful value.